# Is it possible to sort/order by a specific column using the write.csv() function?

Tags: r, export-to-csv

Is it possible to dynamically sort my data by a specific column on-the-fly, during the export (`write.csv()`) function itself?

I export my data thus:

```
write.csv(level_names, "level_names.csv")
```

But want to know if it possible to achieve something like this:

```
write.csv(level_names, "level_names.csv", order(dataset$longname))
```

I know this doesn't work - this is merely for illustration purposes.

Is something to this effect possible?

Comment: Just sort first, `write.csv(x[order(y), ], "file.csv")`

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily contained within that function, but you could easily do something like this using `dplyr`:

```
level_names %>% arrange(longname) %>% write_csv("level_names.csv")
```

Comment: Why someone should load `dplyr` only, and only, for sorting? @Frank I say you post your solution as it makes much more sense to stick to base r here. p.s. `write.csv` is from `utils` which is a base r package.

Comment: OP wasn't looking for a base-only answer - and indeed, dplyr and the tidyverse is used universally in R. I don't know how far you can get with data wrangling without encountering the tidyverse in some capacity.

Comment: I am not saying dplyr is not useful. My point here is base r solution is faster than piping/chaining so it is superior, in my eyes. But anyhow, your solution works. Cheers.